# Custom transition for UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, customization, transition

I would like to customize a transition for UIViewController. Therefore, I created a new category for the push and pop transitions as described here: http://www.davidhamrick.com/2011/12/31/Changing-the-UINavigationController-animation-style.html

So, I created the `T1` category. First, here is the `UINavigationController+T1.h`

```
@interface UINavigationController (T1)

- (void)t1_PushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
- (void)t1_PopViewController;

@end
```

And here is UINavigationContoller+T1.m

```
@implementation UINavigationController (Fade)

- (void)t1_PushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    // ...
    // Push code for T1 transition
    // ...

    [self pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
}

- (void)fadePopViewController
{
    // ...
    // Pop code for T1 transition
    // ...

    [self popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}

@end
```

Then, I am stumped!  I am not sure how to make my UIViewController in the storyboard use those new transitions in the category. How do I force the push and pop transitions in the category I created to be used by the forward (show) and back actions of my UINavigationController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the tutorial [custom-ios-segues-in-xcode-5](http://www.bencz.com/hacks/2014/02/07/custom-ios-segues-in-xcode-5/), as for your case, move the content of `t1_PushViewController` method to `perform` method of your custom `UIStoryboardSegue` subclass, do the same for pop function.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not exactly what I need. It uses Segues' and what I am looking for is using the code in categories to override the push/pop transitions. Maybe it is the same, but I am so lost I do not have a clue.

Comment: It is the same thing, just call `t1_PushViewController` in perform method instead of copying the content of it to `perform`.

Comment: Here is a [project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q2q1a03yf1rgcas/CustomSegue.zip?dl=0) in case you ever need it.